# Basic example of serial communication with Windows XP/win32

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port

I am working with a peripheral device that needs to be communicated through serial.  I can send it commands using HyperTerminal, but now I need to write programs that will let me do it without HyperTerminal.  Can somebody point me to a website and/or show me a sample hello world program to get me started?  I have searched through many sites which give me uncompilable/ancient VC6 code.

Answer (score 6):

In order to interface with the serial port, you open a file with one of the special filenames "COM1" through "COM9".  For serial ports with higher numbers, the special filename begins with \\?\, which in C/C++ code must be escaped as "\\\\?\\COM10", etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx has a really good tutorial on using the serial port.  Note that you should use the Windows file I/O functions such as `CreateFile()`, `ReadFile()`, and `WriteFile()`.  I'm not sure if it will work to use standard I/O functions such as `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fwrite()`.

Comment: Do you think the linked article is still relevant? Is there a better way these days?

Comment: @baordog the linked article [isn't good at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364525/win32-api-how-to-read-the-serial-or-exit-within-a-timeout-if-wasnt-a-data).

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provides [an article with sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx) describing how to do this under Win32.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost:asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) may be able to help as a serial device was added recently.

Fair warning though; the serial port documentation is *light*, presumably since it's quite new (it was added in asio 1.1.1 which was included in boost 1.36).

But working your way through asio is, IMHO, a better solution than using the raw Win32 API.  Why?  It'll be easier to read and maintain (it's a higher level API) and it'll be cross platform (except where you need to specify the OS-specific device name).

The [Boost - Users](http://www.nabble.com/Boost---Users-f14206.html) and [asio.user](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user) mailing lists are quite active and friendly and ought to be able to help you out if you get stuck.

Comment: Boost does a horrible job of Win32 error checking in multi-threaded programs. It outright ignores return values for `WaitForSingleObject`. Use at your own peril, if you don't mind trying to track down their bugs in a threaded program.

Answer (score 1):

If using .NET 2.0 see System.IO.Ports and [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx) should be helpful. If direct Win32, then [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237487/serial-communication-with-windows-xp-win32#237491) is best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find plenty of sample code for C# as well if you find VC6 too ancient.  I think there are also a bunch of "free" serial/COM port wrappers but I just wrote my own when I wrote an RS232 device controller piece of software.

google C# and serial port or rs232

I got these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

You should have no problem finding suitable code with a google search.