# communication to usb port by using vc++2008

Tags: usb, visual-c++-2008

I want to communicate to halios system(hardware) through usb port. I have a code which shows that the device is attached. I used USBTrace which shows that how many bytes are going in and out from the device to the host. But I do not know how to implement this is vc++2008 and by using windows xp.

Comment: Could you provide a link to "halios system(hardware)"?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an evaluation board for an [Elmos optical sensor IC](http://www.elmos.de/english/products/assps/optical-sensors.html) I would guess that a USB to serial converter is involved. You could confirm this by watching Windows Device Manager for a new COM port appearing when you attach the device.

If that's the case you can use [Basic example of serial communication with Windows XP/win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237487/serial-communication-with-windows-xp-win32) but you may need to [contact Elmos](http://www.elmos.de/english/products/contact-service.html) for the command protocol.